# Why 'keydown' detect when I chose select in 'datalist' element (select items from jQuery get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, html-datalist

I type in the input. After each character entered the key down event is detected. I get the elements using ajax GET from .json file and save it to datalist as an option. I want keydown only to fire when typing. Why, when I take one option from datalist 'keydown' is also detect?

Link to code example: https://playcode.io/453516?tabs=script.js,preview,console

For example:

1. I type for example 'c' in input
2. keydown detect
3. in the console I have 'success' and list companies.
4. I select one element from the list
5. keydown select - WHY?
6. List of items don't disappear

My code is here:

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

const inputCompany = $('#company');

inputCompany.keydown('input', debounce(function() {

  //cleaning datalist
  let datalist = document.getElementById('listOfNames');
  while (datalist.lastChild) {
    datalist.removeChild(datalist.lastChild);
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1co0nd',
    data: "value=" + $(this).val().valueOf(),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(data);

      // add elements to datalist
      data.companies.forEach(item => {
        let options = document.createElement('option');
        options.value = item;
        datalist.appendChild(options);
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('error');
    }
  })
}, 250));
```

I expect not to detect 'keydown' when I click on datalist option.

Comment: code link is not accessible, better put it in SO

Comment: maybe try with `inputCompany.on('input', `

Comment: .on doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar, what SO is? I checked link in another computer and it still works.

Comment: SO = stack overflow ... link shared can be lost and this post may not be useful for others to refer so better post you code by editing the question

Comment: Ok, but before the link expires it better shows what the question is about, so you don't have to throw it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case I should use .keypress, because .keypress fires when an actual character is being inserted in, not keyboard key.

Correct code:

```
const inputCompany = $('#company');

inputCompany.keypress('input',
    debounce(function () {

    //cleaning datalist
    let datalist = document.getElementById('listOfNames');
    while (datalist.lastChild) {
        datalist.removeChild(datalist.lastChild);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1co0nd',
        data: "value=" + $(this).val().valueOf(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);

            // add elements to datalist
            data.companies.forEach(item => {
                let options = document.createElement('option');
                options.value = item;
                datalist.appendChild(options);
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    })

}, 250));
```